# TypeError with json data in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I have simple python code that I am using to put the Ask price from an exchange, I get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` when trying to run the following code. I am not sure I under how to handle json data in python.

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1/public/getticker?market=BTC-SHIBE')
jdata = response.json()

assert response.status_code == 200

print jdata[{u'result':{u'Ask'}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the resulting dictionary incorrectly. If you wanted to access the asking price, use:

```
print jdata['result']['Ask']
```

where `'result'` gives you the nested dictionary, which you then access the value associated with `'Ask'` on.

Instead of using an assertion, you can ask the response to raise an exception when there was an error response:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1/public/getticker?market=BTC-SHIBE')
response.raise_for_status()  # raises an exception if not a 2xx or 3xx response

jdata = response.json()

print jdata['result']['Ask']
```

You'd do this *before* you tried to access the JSON data.

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1/public/getticker?market=BTC-SHIBE')
>>> response.raise_for_status()
>>> jdata = response.json()
>>> print jdata['result']['Ask']
9.2e-07
```